# What does mean while(!cursor.isafterlast())

Tags: android, cursor

Hi I am making app with SQLite and I am learning function which reads data and I met this:

```
while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){}
```

What does it mean? What it returns?

Comment: Please, read the documentation before asking here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isAfterLast()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cursor.isAfterLast()` returns `true` when cursor is at last row position. Adding a `!` (not) means perform till it is not at the end of cursor.

so `while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){}` means while loop will traverse till last record of cursor.

Here cursor is a class which holds the row of your data fetch from the table using sql query.

Answer (score 3):

`cursor.isAfterLast()` method returns `true` if you've read all position in your cursor, and `false` in other case.

Each loop iteration must include `cursor.moveToNext()` to change the position of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

`isAfterLast` returns whether this cursor is pointing to the position after the last row or not.

Your code snippet will lead to an infinte loop if it returns true, because of the empty loop body.

If you call `moveToNext` or similar in the body this will iterate over all rows in the cursor.